# Delphi Datasnap Server User Authentication

Tags: delphi, authentication, delphi-xe, datasnap

We are developing a new, and our first, DataSnap server and client apps. I have added authentication to the server but I cannot dynamically change the login details for the connection from the client. The User and Password in the

```
procedure TServerContainer1.DSAuthenticationManager1UserAuthenticate(
  Sender: TObject; const Protocol, Context, User, Password: string;
  var valid: Boolean; UserRoles: TStrings);
```

stays blank.

In the client we set the values as such ...

```
DSConnection := TSQLConnection.Create(nil);
DSConnection.DriverName := 'DATASNAP';
DSConnection.LoginPrompt := False;
DSConnection.Params.Values['port'] :=  Port;
DSConnection.Params.Values['HostName'] :=  HostName;
DSConnection.Params.Values['DSAuthUser'] :=  Username;
DSConnection.OnLogin := DSConnectionOnLogin;
DSProviderConnection1.SQLConnection := DSConnection;
MMLog.Log('DSConnection: ' + DSConnection.Params.Text);
DSConnection.Open;
```

If I however look at `DSConnectEventObject.ConnectProperties.Properties.Text` in the server `OnConnect` event, I can see the parameters as passed.

Am I missing something?

Thanks, Pieter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use the correct Value descriptors.

```
DSConnection.Params.Values['DSAuthUser'] :=  Username;
```

becomes

```
DSConnection.Params.Values['DSAuthenticationUser'] :=  Username;
DSConnection.Params.Values['DSAuthenticationPassword'] := Password;
```

This way the `Authentication Manager` gets the correct username and password.